# Dump selected data to copy of database in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a database in server and its copy in local machine. I want to insert some selected data into local machine. For example,

I have a table with with id = 7 in server
I want to insert the same row in local machine. In both the DBs table name is same. How to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the command line tool mysqldump for this purpose.

```
$ mysqldump -u[db user] -p[db password] [db name] [table name] --where="id = 7" > dump.sql
```

Then import this `dump.sql` to your local server.

```
$ mysql -u[db user] -p[db password] [db name] < dump.sql
```

Hope this is what you want

Comment: I tried this already. It shows no error but I cannot see the data in local DB

Comment: dump.sql is a SQL file, open it up and see if there is any INSERT query in it? Maybe the exported data by `mysqldump` is not what you need. Then try changing --where condition to get the results.